# Undefined method '[ ]' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>

Tags: ruby

Help me pls, i got that NoMethodError when im trying to execute this method

```
def traspuesta()
i=0
aux=nil
    for i in 0..@lt.length do
            aux = @lt[i][0]
            @lt[i][0] = @lt[i][1]
            @lt[i][1] = aux
    end
end
```

the full error says this:

```
Undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>
from MDListaTrip.rb:83:in 'each'
from MDListaTrip.rb:83:in 'traspuesta'
from MDListaTrip.rb:111:in '<main>'
```

Comment: it simply signifies that value of @lt[i] is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for i in 0...@lt.length
```

or

```
for i in 0..@lt.length-1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you use `0..@lt.length` range but you have to use `0..@lt.length-1`. Because of this your last item is nil. And nil object does not respond to `[]` method. That's why you get your error.

To prevent this you can use iterator:

```
@lt.each do |item|
  aux = item[0]
  item[0] = item[1]
  item[1] = aux
end
```